# How exactly is a forEach loop working in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, logic

```js
const navLink = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");
navLink.forEach((link) =>
  link.addEventListener("click", () => {
    ul.classList.remove("show");
  })
);
```

I'm trying to understand the logic behind the forEach in this scenario, I'm new to javascript and programming in general and it's been a challenge to be able to translate what I want into a programing language.

I read different posts regarding forEach syntax but it's truly a lot of technical there and I wasn't able to quite catch their meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDN is both beginner friendly and comprehensive when it comes to web development terms/concepts. In your case: [Array/forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

---

To answer your question precisely, the `forEach` function presented will be run once for each element with a class of `nav-link` found in DOM at the time the script is executed and will add a `click` event listener to each of those elements.

The event listener (the function bound to run when one of the elements is clicked) consists of an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). That function will attempt to remove the class `show` from the HTMLElement referenced by a previously declared variable/constant named `ul`, which is not present in the code you have shown so far.

If `ul` is not referencing an HTMLElement when `.nav-link` is clicked, you will see an error in console complaining `ul` does not have a property called `classList`.

If `ul` is present and references an HTMLElement, the function will remove the class `show` from that element, if the element has that class. Otherwise it will do nothing (without any error/warning).

Answer (score 0):

A `forEach` kinda does what it says. It loops over each element in the array. In your code all the `navLinks` are grabbed and stored into `const navLink` and looped over. After that a `click event` is added to each of them.

The function inside this click event will remove the `show` class from `ul` whenever this click event is triggered. This will be whenever an element with the class `nav-link` is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The forEach function loops over a list of HTML elements or array entries.

In this case, Document#querySelectorAll can return multiple entries, so this allows you to run the same code for each entry.